# How do I improve the performance of the following code in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset with a column of the form:

```
'< 1 year'
'10+ years'
'6 years'
etc
```

I needed it to convert to integer format, that is, '< 1 year' --> 0, '10+ years' --> 10 and entries like '6 years' --> 6 etc. There are 500,000 entries. I wrote the following script to clean it:

```
temp = data.X11
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if ~is_nan(temp[i]):
        if isinstance(temp[i], six.string_types):
            b= temp[i].split(" ")
            if len(b) == 3 and (b[0])=='<':
                temp[i] = 0
            elif len(b) == 2:
                if b[0] == '10+':
                    temp[i] = 10
                else:
                    temp[i] = int(b[0])
        else:
            if isinstance(temp[i], float):
                temp[i] = math.floor(temp[i])
            if isinstance(temp[i], int):
                if temp[i] >= 10:
                    temp[i] = 10
                elif temp[i] < 1 and temp[i] >= 0:
                    temp[i] = 0
                elif temp[i] < 0:
                    temp[i] = -10
                else:
                    pass


    else:
        temp[i] = -10
```

It works. But the downside is, it is awfully slow (took hours to complete). My question is how to improve the performance of this code.

Any advice or help with code snippet would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can do much here.
You can try to avoid the `temp[i]` accesses by iterating the temp values instead. You can also append the new values at the end of another list (fast) instead of modifying a value in the middle (not that fast).

```
new_temp = list()
for temp_i in data.X11:
    if ~is_nan(temp_i):
        if isinstance(temp_i, six.string_types):
            b = temp_i.split(" ")
            if len(b) == 3 and (b[0])=='<':
                new_temp.append(0)
            elif len(b) == 2:
                if b[0] == '10+':
                    new_temp.append(10)
                else:
                    new_temp.append(int(b[0]))
        else:
            if isinstance(temp_i, float):
                new_temp.append(math.floor(temp_i))
            if isinstance(temp_i, int):
                if temp_i >= 10:
                    new_temp.append(10)
                elif temp_i < 1 and temp_i >= 0:
                    new_temp.append(0)
                elif temp_i < 0:
                    new_temp.append(-10)
    else:
        new_temp.append(-10)
```

`string.split` is likely to be very slow.

If it is possible, you can also try to execute your code using [pypy](http://pypy.org) or rewrite it to be compatible with [cython](http://cython.org).

Comment: Thanks for your comments @QuentinRoy

Comment: I will try it out. The solution with dict (see below) is also taking a long time.

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas
You can create a dictionnary , and then map your dataframe with it

```
dico = {'< 1 year' :1,'10+ years' :10,'6 years' :6 }
df['New_var'] = df.var1.map(dico)
```

should only take a couple of seconds

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. But I am not sure about the "var1" in the 2nd line of the code. Could you please briefly explain ? Thanks once again

Comment: I am trying it out now, but it is taking a long time unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think the culprit is this line:

> math.floor(temp[i])

It returns a float which uses quite a few more bits than a standard integer. Casting the result of that operation to an integer could increase performance.

Another solution would be upgrading to [Python 3.x.x](https://www.python.org/downloads/) as in those versions round, [floor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.floor), and ceil all return integers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @DrewB